# L'hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is in reference to a comment on a particular youtube video:'It may be useful to know that when the denominator tends to plus or minus infinity,no matter what the numerator tends to.It may not be an indeterminate form but still we can apply the l'hospital's rule'...that's what the comment looked like.

Now ,is this true? Because during proving l'hospital's rule for infinity over infinity type indeterminate form we usually use the fact that the function at the denominator tends to plus or minus infinity.

Comment: It is true. I think baby Rudin states LH without the unneeded hypothesis. The article on Wiki talks about this. Some authors include the additional hypotheses but do not use it in the proof!

Comment: Can you link the video?

Comment: Sure ...@KingLogic...here is it : https://youtu.be/Vx56JfwE5U8

Comment: This is just one way of proving it, there are two or three such ways .I tried to do it myself also but I faced the same problem.